# Find displacement vector AB, given A is point (-3,5,7) and B is (-5,-4,9)

Tags: matrices, vectors

I am unsure if I answered this questions correctly.

If A is a point with coordinates (-3,5,7) and point B has coordinates (-5,-4,9) then find displacement vector AB.

I got (-8,1,16), is this correct if not, what is the correct answer and how do you do it?

Comment: I'm not sure of the names, but isn't "displacement" $\;AB\;$ the same as the vector $\;\vec{AB}\;$ ? If this is the case, then $\;\vec{AB}=B-A=(-2,-9,2)\;$ ...

Comment: Yes, you are correct about that. I see. I don't what happened there, pretty simple question :)

Comment: Please do not apply the algebraic-geometry tag to elementary problems involving algebra and geometry, as per the tag description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates of point $A$ has first component $-3$, and the coordinates of $B$ has first component $-5$. That means that to get from $A$ to $B$, you have to change the first component by $-2$. Thus the first coordinate of the displacement vector is $-2$.

Do the same for the two other components, and you have your answer. Remember to always go the same way (*from $A$ to* $B$), and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank, the explanation was very helpful.

Comment: @Sam In almost every single case in school math, the formula you learn for something is only of secondary importance to what's _actually_ going on, but people often only really learn the formula. This opens up lots of possibilities for mistakes like adding when you should subtract, or subtracting in the wrong order. Going back to the basics of what you are ultimately after helps avoid such mistakes (although no method is foolproof).